# How to take backup of a database in mysql?

Tags: mysqldump

For Back up I have used the following commands.

```
mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql

mysqldump -u [username] -p[root_password] --single-transaction
 --routines --triggers --lock-tables [database_name] > backup.sql;
```

Getting same error:

> mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show table status like 'uc_order_products_pair_vw'': SELECT command denied to user 'username'@'localhost' for column 'nid' in table 'uc_order_products' (1143)

After running `select * from mysql.tables_priv;`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you try grant permission on whole database like,

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an authorization/rights issue.

Please give the necessary grants to the user 'username' as follows:

```
GRANT SELECT ON uc_order_products TO 'username'@'databasename';
```

OR

```
GRANT SELECT ON uc_order_products TO 'username';
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: thanks for reply. But still getting the same issue.

Comment: Okay.  Could you try with the altered commands (-f option for force backup):  

**mysqldump -f -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql;**

**mysqldump -f -u [username] -p[root_password] --single-transaction
 --routines --triggers --lock-tables [database_name] > backup.sql;**

Comment: Also run the query --> select * from mysql.tables_priv; and check what all grants have been given on table-level and column-level. Then issue those grants to the user with which you are performing the backup.

Comment: i have added the image after run the above query. Also tried force backup but i think it is miss some part in backup. Process completed with some error.

Comment: Okay. I guess a View uc_order_products also exists. So you have to grant the SELECT rights to the user fro that also.

Comment: Grant the select rights but no effects.

Answer (score 0):

> mysqldump -u [username] -p[root_password]
>   --ignore-table=israelca_isr1qaz_2.uc_order_products_pair_vw  --ignore-table=israelca_isr1qaz_2.uc_views_marketing_test --ignore-table=israelca_isr1qaz_2.uc_order_products_user_vw --ignore-table=israelca_isr1qaz_2.uc_order_products_qty_vw israelca_isr1qaz_2 > backup.sql;

Take backup of only tables and ignore the views.